How do I do an inner GroupJoin on dotnet?
I'm using .NET 6 with Entity Framework. This is my situation:
I have a BenefitEntity (with Name and Description properties and a relationship with BenefitCategory) and this BenefitCategory which has Name and Description as well.
In the application, all the Names and Descriptions are translated, we have a TranslationEntities table that contains all the translations.
Here are the three classes (I'll keep it simple and put just the properties we need):
public class BenefitEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid BenefitCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual BenefitCategoryEntity CategoryEntity { get; set; }
}

public class BenefitCategoryEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TranslationEntity
{
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

The TranslationEntities table contains all the translations, for all the entities type. I want to get all the BenefitEntity, using the GroupJoin for their Name/Description and do another inner join for its BenefitCategory name and description. I'm able to do the first one, but not able to do the second one.
Here is what I did:
    public async Task<ICollection<BenefitEntity>> GetAllBenefitEntitiesAsync()
    {
        var benefitsQuery = Entities
            .Include(a => a.CategoryEntity);

        var translationsQuery = DbContext.TranslationsEntities!
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(e => e.Language.Equals(LANGUAGE));

        var benefits = await benefitsQuery.ToListAsync();

        var result = benefits
            .GroupJoin(
                translationsQuery,
                benefit => benefit.Id,
                translation => translation.EntityId,
                (benefit, translation) => new { Benefit = benefit, Translation = translation })
            .Select(result => new BenefitEntity
            {
                    // Benefit Name and Description from joined translations
                    Name = result.Translation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Property.Equals(nameof(BenefitEntity.Name)))?.Value ?? result.Benefit.Name,
                    Description = result.Translation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Property.Equals(nameof(BenefitEntity.Description)))?.Value ?? result.Benefit.Description,
                    Id = result.Benefit.Id,
                    CategoryEntity = result.Benefit.CategoryEntity,
                    BenefitCategoryId = result.Benefit.BenefitCategoryId,
            })
            .AsQueryable();

        return result.ToList();
}

Starting from that point, how can I do another Join for CategoryEntity, using the same translationQuery, joining the categoryEntity.Id with translation.EntityId ?

If you have several joins, better to use Query Expression synatx. It is maintanable and easy to understand for those who know SQL.
So, the following is variant should be effective, even without GroupJoin. Not used it here, because EF Core has problems with this operator fom version to version.
public Task<ICollection<BenefitEntity>> GetAllBenefitEntitiesAsync()
{
    var benefitsQuery = Entities;

    var translationsQuery = DbContext.TranslationsEntities!
       .Where(e => e.Language == LANGUAGE);

    var query = 
        from b in benefitsQuery
        from nameT in translationsQuery
            .Where(nameT => nameT.EntityId == b.Id && nameT.Property == nameof(BenefitEntity.Name))
            .Take(1)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
        from descT in translationsQuery
            .Where(descT => descT.EntityId == b.Id && descT.Property == nameof(BenefitEntity.Description))
            .Take(1)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new BenefitEntity
        {
            // Benefit Name and Description from joined translations
            Name = nameT.Value ?? b.Name,
            Description = descT.Value ?? b.Description,
            Id = b.Id,
            CategoryEntity = b.CategoryEntity,
            BenefitCategoryId = b.BenefitCategoryId,
        };

    return query.ToListAsync();
} 

I suppose you have a lot of such queries, I would suggest to get LINQKit and write helper method in your context
public class YouDbContext : DbContext // name of your context
{
    [Expandable(nameof(GetTranslationImpl))]
    public string GetTranslation(string language, int entityId, string property, string currentValue)
        => throw new InvlaidOperationException("Should not be called directly");

    // Expression for substitution
    static Expression<Func<YouDbContext, string, int, string, string>> GetTranslationImpl()
        => (ctx, language, entityId, property, currentValue) =>
            ctx.TranslationsEntities.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Language == language && t.EntityId == entityId && t.Property == property).Value ?? currentValue;
}

For EF Core, activate extension during options building:
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)  // or any other database
    .WithExpressionExpanding();      // enabling LINQKit extension

For EF 6, use AsExpandable() before ToListAsync()
Then we can simplify our query:
public Task<ICollection<BenefitEntity>> GetAllBenefitEntitiesAsync()
{
    var query = Entities
        .Select(b => new BenefitEntity
        {
            // Benefit Name and Description from joined translations
            Name = DbContext.GetTranslation(LANGUAGE, b.Id, nameof(BenefitEntity.Name), b.Name),
            Description = DbContext.GetTranslation(LANGUAGE, b.Id, nameof(BenefitEntity.Description), b.Description),
            Id = b.Id,
            CategoryEntity = b.CategoryEntity,
            BenefitCategoryId = b.BenefitCategoryId,
        });

    return query.ToListAsync();
} 


In this updated code:
A new Select has been added to materialize the translations into a list for multiple use.
New properties CategoryName and CategoryDescription have been added to BenefitEntity to hold translated values for BenefitCategoryEntity.
Translated values for BenefitCategoryEntity.Name and BenefitCategoryEntity.Description are fetched using the same translation logic.
 public async Task<ICollection<BenefitEntity>> GetAllBenefitEntitiesAsync() { var benefitsQuery = Entities .Include(a => a.CategoryEntity);

var translationsQuery = DbContext.TranslationsEntities!
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(e => e.Language.Equals(LANGUAGE));

var benefits = await benefitsQuery.ToListAsync();

var result = benefits
    .GroupJoin(
        translationsQuery,
        benefit => benefit.Id,
        translation => translation.EntityId,
        (benefit, translation) => new { Benefit = benefit, Translation = translation })
    .Select(result => new
    {
        Benefit = result.Benefit,
        Translation = result.Translation.ToList()
    })
    .Select(result => new BenefitEntity
    {
        // Benefit Name and Description from joined translations
        Name = result.Translation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Property.Equals(nameof(BenefitEntity.Name)))?.Value ?? result.Benefit.Name,
        Description = result.Translation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Property.Equals(nameof(BenefitEntity.Description)))?.Value ?? result.Benefit.Description,
        Id = result.Benefit.Id,
        CategoryEntity = result.Benefit.CategoryEntity,
        BenefitCategoryId = result.Benefit.BenefitCategoryId,
        CategoryName = result.Translation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Property.Equals(nameof(BenefitCategoryEntity.Name)))?.Value ?? result.Benefit.CategoryEntity.Name,
        CategoryDescription = result.Translation.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Property.Equals(nameof(BenefitCategoryEntity.Description)))?.Value ?? result.Benefit.CategoryEntity.Description
    })
    .AsQueryable();`enter code here`

return result.ToList();
}


How should I find the category translations in this way? In the result.Translation I expect to find only just the BenefitName and BenefitDescription (because they match the Benefit.Id with translation.EntityId), but not the category.. BenefitCategory.Id is different from Benefit.Id
